# Setting UITableViewCellStyle2 Tint Color

Tags: ios7

I can't believe I don't see this anywhere on Google, but I have an odd issue.

I am changing the Global Tint in iOS 7 in the App Delegate:
`[[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];`

However, when I display a table view with UITableViewCellStyle2 cells, the text title color is still the default blue color.

Any ideas on how I could fix this? I'd rather not subclass it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply change the text color.

```
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: True, but since I am specifying the color it won't use the global tint color, unless I can find a way to read that. Oh well. Marking yours as answered- I thought this would be the best possible solution but I was hoping for a better one.